# Go on default why the other cases are not getting printed out

Tags: go

When I run this code I don’t understand why after printing X it does not print the other cases.
I expect that I should see X print it out for three seconds and then finally from server2

```
package main


func server1(ch chan string) {
    time.Sleep(6 * time.Second)
    ch <- "from server1"
}
func server2(ch chan string) {
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    ch <- "from server2"

}
func main() {
    output1 := make(chan string)
    output2 := make(chan string)
    go server1(output1)
    go server2(output2)
    select {
    case s1 := <-output1:
        fmt.Println(s1)
    case s2 := <-output2:
        fmt.Println(s2)
    default:
        fmt.Println(“X”)
    }
}
```

Comment: When main exist the programs terminates, including all of its goroutines, they don't continue on in the ether.

Comment: You need to put your select statement inside a loop.

Comment: Thanks makes sense . Sorry Starting to learn go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func main() {
    output1 := make(chan string)
    output2 := make(chan string)
    go server1(output1)
    go server2(output2)
    for {
        select {
        case s1 := <-output1:
            fmt.Println(s1)
        case s2 := <-output2:
            fmt.Println(s2)
        default: // todo: return
            fmt.Println("X")
        }
    }
}
```